# Add missing features to attribute table

Tags: qgis, merge, table

I have two tables with complementing data in them. Both have an ID column (tree_ID). Table A is missing several features which are in table B.

How can i copy only features from B to A which are NOT already in A using QGIS?

In pseudocode i search for something like:

```
Select features from B where B.ID is not already in A.ID
```

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by field`? If so, how does the outcome not suite you needs?

Comment: when i do a join, columns from B will be added to A where it does find a matching ID. I want features which are not in A copied from B to A ( the columns are identical for both layers)

Comment: Ah, sorry, the whole feature is missing, not only the attributes. Then how about `merge vector layers` and `delete duplicate geometries`?

Comment: well, as B is a updated version of A but i have no attribute from which i could determine after the merge from which table the feature originates, this does not work. unfortunately, the points do not share exactly the same coordinates (something went wrong during the crs transformation)

Comment: But if B is an update to A... why not use only B? I'm lazy, sorry ;-)

Comment: because B includes only the updated (changed or newly created) features :)

Comment: You could use the `aggregate`-function as argument based on the ID for `select by expression` to select/extract all features in A which are not in B, the `merge` the selected/extracted data - but to be honest I can't wrap my head around the code. Guess I am missing a filterexpression...

Comment: Couldn't you add a column to your table B (something like Boolean-field, named "table_B" and values all set to TRUE). After merging vector layer, you could check with this added attribute which rows came from B. For selecting double geometries, even if they share not exactly the same coordinates, you could apply a small buffer around each point: if it contains another point, it can be considered a duplicate - and you can delete one of the two (based on attribute-value in row "table_B": the points from A (value=false) of those from B (value=true).

Comment: ah well, thats exactly how i got it solved now! thanks @babel!